Should I remove a reference after applying to job?
I applied to job about 1.5 months ago and just got a call back for an interview.
During that time frame, I had a few work disagreements with one of the references on my application. I am no longer confident in their ability to recommend me.
What's the best thing to do in this situation? I was thinking about letting them know during the interview that I no longer have a good relationship on with one this reference, but I wonder if that would make me look bad. There's also the chance that they won't even contact the reference.
Wondering if there are any managers here that could let me know how they'd view a candidate if they told you not to contact one of the listed references.

For what it's worth, if you're in the United States, many companies now have a policy that the references can't do much more than indicate whether you worked for the company, and whether you were fired, laid off, or left on your own. Anything more is opening them up to legal liability. Not that that always stops people from gossiping, but it has created a strong incentive.

@SeanDuggan Couldn't that information be provided by the HR Dept of the former companies? The point of human references is to sing your praises.

It's been a while since I've applied for a job, but references were generally provided pretty late in the process, after the interview if the company is still interested. How did this company get your references already?

@Barmar: The process has changed, but when I was actively applying a decade or two ago, references were standard on most applications (and most resumes had standard boilerplate of "References available upon request" that I finally removed when I realized how meaningless it was).

@Barmar: Yeah, but if you make a mistake while singing, you get sued. In countries like Austria and Germany, which have strong employee protection laws, reference letters have effectively become completely useless, since every kind of assessment that is not absolute and unrealistic praise can (and will!) get you in legal trouble.

@SeanDuggan "many companies now have a policy that the references can't do much more than indicate whether you worked for the company" - if someone is asked as a representative of the company (e.g. if they call HR), sure. But I'm skeptical whether this applies if you give someone as a personal reference.

When you go in, provide an updated list of references.  “Here’s my updated list of references!”  Done.  Of course if you can get a new one to add all the better.

I like this the best.  Sweet and simple.  I agree that it is better to just give them the updated list without any explanations.

You can prepare a revised list of references. During the interview, you don't necessarily need to bring up the negative situation unless asked specifically about that reference.
But you can explain briefly, without going into too much detail, that you've updated your references to include individuals who can provide the most relevant and recent information about your qualifications.
Here’s how you can phrase it:
"I've updated my list of references with people who know my recent work better and can give you the most accurate picture of my skills and performance."

This is golden. SPECIFICALLY don't mention the reference that you are removing.  If it's noticed, you can say that the person is not currently in a good position to give a reference -- which would be true.

To me this seems to imply that you also at least added one or more new references when you phrase it like this. So I would say you can't really say this if you only removed references

I disagree. It's an update either way.

Technically, it is an update either way, but it's much better if a reference was added.
